# Spring MVC & Freemarker/Velocity

Tags: java, spring, session, velocity, freemarker

I've got a problem with Freemarker's and Velocity's view resolver (not running at same moment) - both of them don't see Spring's session beans. Spring's InternalResourceViewResolver works good.

Some code:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.revicostudio.web" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="userSession" class="com.revicostudio.web.session.UserSession" scope="session" /> 

<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="layoutUrl" value="layout.jsp"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc" />
</bean>
```

In jsp:

```
${userSession}<br /> <!-- Null if Freemarker's view resolver active, session object if Spring's resolver active -->
${error}<br /> <!-- Normal request attribute, put to map, that works good in both resolvers -->
```

IndexController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userRegisterCredentials")
    public UserRegisterCredentials getUserRegisterCredentials() {
        return new UserRegisterCredentials();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userLoginCredentials")
    public UserLoginCredentials getUserLoginCredentials() {
        return new UserLoginCredentials();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You should annotate controller to point out which model attribute should be exposed in a session
2.In freemarker, access to session attrs is done by a freemarker session wrapper.

Short example below, based on Your code:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userRegisterCredentials")
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userRegisterCredentials")
    public UserRegisterCredentials getUserRegisterCredentials() {
        return new UserRegisterCredentials();
    }    

}
```

On the ftl side:${Session.userRegisterCredentials.someStringField}